# Python error opening plugin manager in Quantum GIS

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-plugins

I just attempted to update my version of QGIS from something like 2.2.0 (can't remember exactly what it used to be) to 2.6.0 and now encounter an error - copied below - when I try to open the Plugin Manager/Installer.

I uninstalled my previous version of QGIS first and, in addition to QGIS 2.6.0, downloaded the latest versions of Python, NumPy, matplotlib, and GDAL as recommended on the site.

I've tried reinstalling older versions of QGIS again, but the error pops up all the time now.

Sadly, I wanted to update the program in order to access the latest plugins.  I'm on Mac OS X 10.8.5.

```
An error has occured while executing Python code:


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Applications/QGIS.app/Contents/MacOS/../Resources/python/pyplugin_installer/installer_data.py", line 460, in xmlDownloaded
    if isCompatible(QGis.QGIS_VERSION, qgisMinimumVersion, qgisMaximumVersion):
  File "/Applications/QGIS.app/Contents/MacOS/../Resources/python/pyplugin_installer/version_compare.py", line 188, in isCompatible
    if len(maxVer)TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len()


Python version:
2.7.9 (v2.7.9:648dcafa7e5f, Dec 10 2014, 10:10:46) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)]


QGIS version:
2.6.0-Brighton Brighton, 

Python path: ['/Applications/QGIS.app/Contents/MacOS/../Resources/python/plugins/processing', '/Applications/QGIS.app/Contents/MacOS/../Resources/python', u'/Users/Lucy/.qgis2/python', u'/Users/Lucy/.qgis2/python/plugins', '/Applications/QGIS.app/Contents/MacOS/../Resources/python/plugins', '/Library/Frameworks/SQLite3.framework/Versions/C/Python/2.7', '/Library/Frameworks/GEOS.framework/Versions/3/Python/2.7', '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/numpy-override', '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/matplotlib-override', '/Library/Frameworks/GDAL.framework/Versions/1.11/Python/2.7/site-packages', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python27.zip', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-darwin', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac/lib-scriptpackages', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-tk', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-old', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages', '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages', '/Users/Lucy/.qgis2/python/plugins/mmqgis/forms', '/Applications/QGIS.app/Contents/Resources/python/plugins/fTools/tools']
```